# How to separate Hours minutes and seconds from data using tidyr Package in R language?

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is the data i had

```
  temp           time_hour
1 37.04      2013-01-01 05:30:00
2 37.04      2013-01-01 06:30:00
3 37.94      2013-01-01 07:30:00
4 37.94      2013-01-01 08:30:00
5 37.94      2013-01-01 09:30:00
```

Now i need to separate the time_hour column to **"date","month","year"** and also to **"Hours","minutes","seconds"** using tidyr package in R programming languages. I used separate variables to separate **date, month, year**. i don't know how to separate time like **hours, minutes, seconds**. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    separate(time_hour, into = c("year", "month", "day", "hour", "minutes", "seconds"))
#   temp year month day hour minutes seconds
#1 37.04 2013    01  01   05      30      00
#2 37.04 2013    01  01   06      30      00
#3 37.94 2013    01  01   07      30      00
#4 37.94 2013    01  01   08      30      00
#5 37.94 2013    01  01   09      30      00
```